# Ошибка The mbstring extension is missing?

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Имею на машине LEMP сервер. При попытке поставить на него phpmyadmin выдает ошибку

> The mbstring extension is missing. Please check your PHP
>   configuration.

Хотя при выполнении команды php -m модуль mbstring выводится. В конфиге тоже всё подключено. Как исправить такую штуку?

Немного погодя заметил, что при выводе всех модулей вылезает ошибка:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring.so' (tried: ./mbstring.so (./mbstring.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), ./mbstring.so.so (./mbstring.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

---

Спустя несколько часов изучения документации, я пришел к выводу, что было установлено много лишних расширений. Я переустановил php и все заработало

Comment: Добавьте строку конфига с `php_mbstring.dll`

Comment: @InDevX в каком смысле? не понял вас

Comment: `php.ini` знаете что такое? Вот, в этом файле должна быть строка с выше приведённым текстом

Comment: @InDevX да, есть она. Раскомментированная

Comment: закомментируйте, если она с расширением `.dll`

Comment: @InDevX она без расширения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что у вас установлен пакет php-mbstring. Если нет - установите:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Чтобы включить расширение mb_string:

```
$ sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

Comment: Установил, убедился. Все равно не работает

Comment: @МишаКуликовский ребутнулись?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin да